# Color detection of object in Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, rgb

I am using opencv and python .

**I need to detect color of object in image for example given below image , the color of shirt is red.**

[image]

[image]

On this link i found something useful but its detecting image of skin .
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/

I think i will have to use image contour extraction and then carry out color detection for that .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting the dominant colors may be achieved using the following simple approach:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

img = cv2.imread('red_shirt.jpg')
height, width, dim = img.shape
```

**EDIT:**  take only the center of the image:

```
img = img[(height/4):(3*height/4), (width/4):(3*width/4), :]
height, width, dim = img.shape

img_vec = np.reshape(img, [height * width, dim] )

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit( img_vec )
```

**EDIT:** count cluster pixels, order clusters by cluster size

```
unique_l, counts_l = np.unique(kmeans.labels_, return_counts=True)
sort_ix = np.argsort(counts_l)
sort_ix = sort_ix[::-1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x_from = 0.05

for cluster_center in kmeans.cluster_centers_[sort_ix]:
    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle( (x_from, 0.05), 0.29, 0.9, alpha=None,
                                    facecolor='#%02x%02x%02x' % (cluster_center[2], cluster_center[1], cluster_center[0] ) ) )
    x_from = x_from + 0.31

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can remove BG and skin pixels with [this kind of preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822154/image-processing-dress-segmentation-using-opencv?noredirect=1#comment61252020_36822154)

Comment: Nice ill check that out , this is the thing i was looking for

Comment: if you only need a single color you can use several heuristics for choosing the right color based on location, saturation and pixel count, but that depends on the appearance of your input and the exact requirements

Comment: I am removing background image and then trying to find out the color , bez most of the time its giving me white as first choice

Comment: I have modified the code to use only the image center and order the clusters by size

Comment: ohh thanks i was trying to do using background subtraction

Comment: Rosa Gronchi thanks for help but problem is sometimes when i want to check for pant bez of gay the main color is picked as white which i dont want , any suggestion alternative

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: is the bg always white? can the items be completely white? can you ignore white pixels?

Comment: Problem if t shirt is white

Comment: background can be anycolor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111104/discussion-between-rosa-gronchi-and-usernan).

Comment: Nice ! Thanks ! How do you get the color as an object you can compare with others images ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Load the frame
2. Convert BGR to HSV
3. Range the value of pixel

also check out this link [Color detection in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189482/color-detection-in-opencv)

Comment: Above sol which u said is when u want to detect given color example detect blue color in image . but i want find out what is color of image